# Laravel Homestead & WordPress deleting plugins needs FTP?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, homestead

Although I have wp-cli installed I don't want this to pose any further issues potentially in development. I have Homestead running with libvirt provider (rather than Virtualbox, e.g.) via vagrant-mutate and a WP site in Apache (synced folders via NFS). But to delete a plugin it says, "To perform the requested action, WordPress needs access to your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed." I tried doing `chown -Rf www-data.www-data .` in the site directory which resulted in everything saying "No input file specified", so I just reinstalled it. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
// find your full path by PWD (Present working directory) Linux command then try following example command 

pwd 

// Check this command in SSH 

    chown -R www-data:www-data /your/target/fullpath/

// you may try with Sudo power 

 sudo  chown -R www-data:www-data /your/target/fullpath/

// if you need this ownership change for all sub foders 

    chown -R maximilian:maximilian /your/target/fullpath/
```